# transfering value from one page to another in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

i have three pages a,b and c all pages have checkbox control.i transfer the value of one control on page b to page a by query with navigation method and when i transfer page c value to page a the previous value that is transfered to another control previously is removed on transfering value how can i save it so that it remain on the page.

please help me in finding solution
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **PhoneApplicationService.Current.State**.

It works like session variables.

This is how you can use it:

Page 1 - *//saving the value*

**variable 1=[your value];**

**PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["any session variable name"] = variable 1;**

Page 2 - *//retrieving the value*

**variable 2 = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["any session variable name"];**